# Thermofans not staying on long enough?

Tags: honda, cooling-system, accord, radiator

I am working on a 1988 Honda Accord (2lt, injected, A-series engine) that has been sitting a while. I am getting an issue with it overheating (after about 20 mins idling).

The thermofans kick on at the right time - when the temperature gauge reaches about half way. They will run for about 20 seconds, then switch off, then come on again maybe 3 mins later. Meanwhile the temperature just creeps up and up.

I have done the following:

- Flushed cooling system (lots of gunk in there)
- Replaced thermostat
- Replaced water pump
- Replaced radiator cap

Radiator visual appears fine, but could this mean it's toast? Anything else this could be?

Answer (score 1):

I would look at replacing your temperature sensor, as it is telling the computer to turn on fans, But, its not keeping the fans running. Good likelyhood it is defective and there cheap 15-30$ most of the time with exceptions.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!